# Failed to sign transaction, error: Non-plaintext key sent to plaintext handler

Tags: wallets

Using Account Viewer from Stellar website I try to send XLM exactly the same way and to exactly the same address as few days ago. No problem before, but this time always this error message comes: Failed to sign transaction, error: Non-plaintext key sent to plaintext handler
So what's wrong and how to fix it? Please!

Answer (score 0):

Please try it under Firefox. I'm able to reproduce the same issue in Chrome, but don't see it in Firefox for an identical transaction.